# How to setup/upgrade database for a Blazor Server app without using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, installation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm thinking about this for quite a while now. I want to publish my Blazor Server app so it can be used by everyone on a self-hosted basis. My app is using a database so within my company it's no problem to setup a database and insert the corresponding connection string into `appSettings.json`

So far so good. The issue now comes when someone else want's to host the application then he'll need to setup the database by himself and put the ConnectionString into the `appsettings.json`. This however comes with another issue. When I ship an update, the `appsettings.json` will be overwritten and the connection string needs to be put inside it again. Furthermore he'll needs to check if there are any database changes which he/she needs to apply by hand. We don't need to argue that this is absolutely unmanageable.

But I couldn't figure out how I can setup a default Blazor Server app todo this stuff automatically.

What I'm trying to achieve is on startup of the app, it should check if it needs to setup the database. If there is no database setup it should start with some kind of wizard where the connection data needs to be inserted first by the user. Afterwards it should create the database.

My main issues here are:

1. How do I detected if the database doesn't exist? Is it a good practice to just check for an empty connection string?
2. How do I save the connection string from the user so it won't get overwritten during an update of the app?
3. How can I display a different UI in Blazor for this setup process? For example, when no database exists it should only allow to open `/install` and none of the other pages
4. How do I switch back to the normal UI when the database has been setup?

Or in terms of code in `Program.cs`

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
var config = builder.Configuration;

string? connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("Default");
// THE DATABASE DOES NOT EXIST WHEN THERE IS NO CONNECTION STRING AVAILABLE or 
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
{
    // THE APP HASN'T BEEN INSTALLED YET. SO WE'LL NEED TO START THE WIZARD
    // SHOW WIZARD UI AND HIDE DEFAULT UI
    // AFTER THE WIZARD IS DONE, IT SHOULD BE DISABLED AND THE DEFAULT UI SHOULD BE ENABLED
}
else
{
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    // CHECK IF THE DATABASE NEEDS TO BE UPGRADED
    // IF TRUE THEN UPGRADE IT AUTOMATICALLY
}
```

Does anyone have any experience with setting up the database for third party users and is able to guide me to the right way?